# why .netstandard 1.4 is NetStandard.Library 1.6?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

I have created a .net core class library package and uploaded it to nuget.org

In the dependencies section is says that my project depends on .NetStandard 1.4, that is NetStandard.Library higher than 1.6

Why is there such a confuse mismatch in the version number?
Aren't .NetStandard and NetStandard.Library supposed to be the same thing? Or are they different things?

here is my .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
    <PackageVersion>2.0.1</PackageVersion>
    <AssemblyName>currency</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

and the link to my project:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/currency/

Comment: .NET Standard is just a set of API on the paper, while .NET Standard Library is the actual implementation of such API. As the SDK will resolve .NET Standard Library version for you, don't bother much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found an interesting page about the .NETStandard.Library:

[What is the .NETStandard.Library metapackage?](https://andrewlock.net/what-is-the-netstandard-library-metapackage/)

On this page the author say the following:

> So even if your project is targeting .NET Standard version 1.3 (or multi-targeting), you can still use the latest NETStandard.Library package version (1.6.1 at the time of writing). The package itself is versioned primarily because it also contains various tooling support such as the list of .NET Standard versions.

---

In the documentation of Microsoft, I have found the following information about your question:

> It may seem strange to target netstandard1.3 but use the 1.6.0 version of NETStandard.Library. It is a valid use-case, since the metapackage maintains support for older netstandard versions. It could be the case you've standardized on the 1.6.0 version of the metapackage and use it for all your libraries, which target a variety of netstandard versions. With this approach, you only need to restore NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 and not earlier versions.

Link: [Look at .NetStandard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/packages)

I think, it will ever use the latest version of the .NETStandard.Library, because it is compatible with older versions of .NETStandard and it is only a metapackage with references and a set of standard .Net APIs. So it shouldn't be a problem, if your package use the .NETStandard.Library version 1.6.1

Notice: If you use .NETStandard 2.0 and you use .NETStandard.Library version 1.6.1, it can't work!

---

**Update**: Like svick mention in the comments of this answer, the minimum version of the .NETStandard.Library is the version 1.6.0!

Comment: Your post makes it sound like you *could* decide to use `NETStandard.Library` version 1.3. But you can't, that version doesn't exist, only 1.6.0+.